# Division of two numbers in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, integer-division

Starting to teach myself assembly (NASM) I wanted to know how to divide 2 numbers (For instance on Windows).

My code looks like this but it crashes.

```
global _main
extern _printf

section .text

_main:

mov eax, 250
mov ebx, 25
div ebx
push ebx
push message 

call _printf
add esp , 8
ret

message db "Value is = %d", 10 , 0
```

I wonder what's really wrong? It doesn't even display the value after the division.

Comment: Consult an instruction set reference about how `div` works. Hint: the dividend is a 64 bit value, you need to zero `edx`. Also, calling convention mandates `ebx` to be preserved and the result won't be in `ebx` anyway.

Comment: The assembly instructions don't follow wishes or logic, i.e. just because some instruction is called "DIV", it doesn't mean it works as you expect. But your code looks like you didn't check the instruction manual. You need the instruction reference guide [(simplified web version here)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) (but in rare cases don't hesitate to use official Intel docs) for ASM programming, to check it often for all kinds of instructions (especially when flags are involved, or other tricky subtle details, like `DIV` behaviour).

Answer (score 12):

Your instruction `div ebx` divides the *register pair* `edx:eax` (which is an *implicit operand* for this instruction) by the provided *source operand* (i.e.: the *divisor*).

---

```
mov edx, 0
mov eax, 250
mov ecx, 25
div ecx
```

In the code above `edx:eax` is the *dividend* and `ecx` is the *divisor*.
After executing the `div` instruction the register `eax` contains the *quotient* and `edx` contains the *remainder*.

---

I am using the register `ecx` instead of `ebx` for holding the divisor because, as [stated in the  comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506439/division-of-two-numbers-in-nasm#comment77973613_45506439), the register `ebx` has to be preserved between calls. Otherwise it has to be properly *saved* before being modified and *restored* before returning from the corresponding subroutine.

---

#### *Divide by zero error* may occur

As [stated in one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45506439/division-of-two-numbers-in-nasm/45508617#comment78035728_45537825), if the quotient does not fit within the rage of the quotient register (`eax` in this case), a *divide by zero error* does occur.

This may explain why your program is crashing: since the register `edx` is not being set prior to executing the `div` instruction, it might contain a value so large, that the resulting quotient doesn't fit in the `eax` register.

Comment: I'm already aware of the fact that either `cdq` after setting `eax` or `xor edx, edx` would perform better than `mov edx, 0`. I just used the latter to keep the code simpler to understand.

Comment: `cdq` sign extends eax into edx, it doesn't zero extend it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you are right, `cdq` sign extends `eax` into `edx` and it is therefore suited for `idiv` and not `div`.

Comment: This explains about using div correctly, but doesn't explain why the code crashes rather than printing the value is 25. In most assemblers, "push message" pushes the first 4 bytes of message rather than the address of message. But in NASM, that syntax does push the address. So the crash is still unexplained.

Answer (score -2):

The other comments and answer explain about using div correctly, but they don't explain why your code crashes rather than printing the wrong result. In most assemblers, "push message" pushes the first 4 bytes of message rather than the address of message, which is what printf expects. In NASM, as far as I can tell, it pushes the address. But you should double check that, since I don't use NASM.

Comment: In NASM syntax, it pushes the address.  You always need `[]` around something to make it a memory reference.

Comment: Also, it may be crashing with SIGFPE (or the windows equivalent) if the quotient doesn't fit in a 32-bit register.  (Same error as division by zero.)